# How to check if password is valid if username, encrypted password, and salt were stored in MySQL?

Tags: java

So I have a simple login and registration web app in Java. My registration file inserts the data into MySQL database as follows

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String user_name = request.getParameter("name");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    
    // encrypt password 
    String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
    byte[] salt = new byte[16]; // Use a cryptographically secure random number generator to generate the salt
    new SecureRandom().nextBytes(salt);

    // Hash the password with bcrypt
    String hashedPassword = OpenBSDBCrypt.generate(pass.toCharArray(), salt, 12);
    
    String mobile = request.getParameter("contact");
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = null;
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/LOGIN?useSSL=false", "username", "password");
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into users(user_name, salt, hashed_pass, email, mobile) values(?,?,?,?,?) ");
        pst.setString(1, user_name);
        pst.setBytes(2, salt);
        pst.setString(3, hashedPassword);
        pst.setString(4, email);
        pst.setString(5, mobile);
} 
...
```

In MySQL database, I have a `users` table as follows

```
create table users (
   id int primary key auto_increment,
   user_name varchar(50),
   salt varbinary(16),
   hashed_pass varchar(60),
   email varchar(50),
   mobile varchar(20)
  );
```

Originally, before hashing password, my login file would validate data as follows (`pass` was the plain password that user registers with)

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String email = request.getParameter("username");
    String pass = request.getParameter("password");
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = null;
    
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/LOGIN?useSSL=false", "username", "password");
        String query = "select * from users where email = ? and pass = ?";
        pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
        pst.setString(1, email);
        pst.setString(2, pass);
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        
        if (rs.next()) {
            session.setAttribute("name", rs.getString("user_name"));
            dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
        } else {
            request.setAttribute("status", "failed");
            dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
        }
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        rs.close();
}
 ....
```

I'm not exactly sure how would I check if the original password matches the encrypted password in the database here. I've tried looking up but haven't found anything yet. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Do exactly the same thing to the offered password that you did to the original password and see if you can find such a row. NB `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")` hasn't been needed for 18 years.

Comment: Wait sorry, so how do I modify the query in the login file? That is the part where I got stuck.

Comment: You don't have to modify the query. You have to modify `pass`, just as you did the first time, before doing `ps.setString(2, hashedPassword )`.

Comment: Oh I see. I think the part where I got confused was how to get the exact salt (do I need that or regardless we still have the same generated password?) Or should I just do the exact same thing as the first time and replace pass with HashedPassword?

Comment: Keep using the same salt value. Store it in the database somewhere and never change it. Or make it a constant in your code.

Comment: Or use the bytes of the username as the salt.

Comment: If you do use the bytes of the username as a salt, then also augment it with something unique to your site (a "pepper"), otherwise the user's password hash will match those stored on other sites should the same user use the same password elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the salt is a unique value stored in each `users` record, you would need to first retrieve the `users` record by the unique ID given in the login, e.g. `email`.  You extract the `salt` from that record, hash the password given in the login using the retrieved salt, and then compare that with the `hashed_pass` value in the retrieved record.  If they match, use the retrieved record, otherwise discard it and fail the login.